# Errors from C# 6.0 syntax

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, lambda, resharper, c#-6.0

I turned on C# 6.0 as Resharper suggested. I love the changes but it appears to me Visual Studio 2013 and C# 6.0 don't really like each other because when I use lambdas for operators like in

```
public static MVector operator +(MVector l, MVector r) => new MVector(l.X+r.X, l.Y+r.Y);
```

It says there should be a ';' instead of the lambda but doesn't underline it with red. I turned everything I could to lambdas in that file and got lots of errors but nothing is underlined which is weird.

Comment: yes. resharper suggest for enabling this feature but it does not work and you have to get vs 2015.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 doesn't support C# 6.0. Visual Studio 2015 (which will RTM on 2015-07-20) does.

Visual Studio 2013 used to support some beta version of Roslyn, but that wasn't updated to the latest versions of Roslyn.